# Running climate models with ClimateNA and *.asc (ASCII) SpatRaster causes - Run time error 62 ''Input past end of file'

Tags: qgis, r, terra, climatena

I am trying to use the [ClimateNA](https://climatena.ca/) software using a 250 m DEM SpatRaster that I have exported from R using the terra package into ASCII (*.asc) format as is required. I can successfully export my DEM and open it with QGIS as *.asc file. I addressed some of the more technical ends to replace NaN / NA (i.e., no data values) with -9999 by using `subst()` function and also used the terra function:

`WriteRaster(x, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE, ,NAFlag=-9999)`; see [here](https://%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78189012/issues-with-saving-terra-asc-files-couldnt-find-data-values-in-ascii-grid/78190667?noredirect=1#comment137934764_78190667).

I can plot my maps in R and open the saved *.asc files in QGIS successfully. I set my SpatRaster DEM values to integers to match the example data (*.asc files) provided with the ClimateNA software. ClimateNA works with the example data in the downloaded distribution. I even set my `crs()` to match the ClimateNA example data. However, the SpatRaster of the example ClimateNA data (e.g., `>BC800cp.asc`), has no min max values showing but otherwise looks the same as my SpatRaster. The ClimateNA example plots with a scale bar showing a distribution of values. Everything looks identical to my SpatRaster, except if I print my SpatRaster (e.g., `>myDEM`), I see values as min:-500 max:2400 (numbers may vary depending on the scale). If I convert the ClimateNA *.asc SpatRaster to a data frame, the range of values are min:-Inf max:Inf.

If I run my *.asc DEM, exported from terra, using ClimateNA, I get a "Run time error 62 ''Input past end of file'".

Why am I getting this error to fix / set my *.asc files to work in ClimateNA?

I simplified my raster down to 10 rows to create an example that produces the same error:

```
> CDEM_df
           x       y elev
1  -125.0971 59.9989 977
2  -125.0935 59.9989 1011
3  -125.0899 59.9989 1043
4  -125.0863 59.9989 1069
5  -125.0827 59.9989 1106
6  -125.0790 59.9989 1142
7  -125.0754 59.9989 1169
8  -125.0718 59.9989 1186
9  -125.0682 59.9989 1194
10 -125.0646 59.9989 1204

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f, nlyr=ncol(CDEM_df))
values(r) <- as.matrix(CDEM_df)
names(r) <- colnames(CDEM_df)
r2 <- r[[3]]

writeRaster(r2,filename="C:/CDEM_example.asc"),
                   overwrite=TRUE, NAflag=-9999)
```

Comment: Hard to tell something reliable without the issue being producible. The missing min/max values of your data sample might be a consequence of your values not being indexed... So maybe the table has to be computed first. What happens if you execute `r <- terra::rast("BC800cp.asc"); r*1`? Do the files *really* look the same? Try inspecting them using a plain text editor (yay, human readable format), e.g. Notepad++, for delimiters, separators and also special characters (EOL, EOF)?

Comment: I edited to give a min reproduceable example.

Comment: Still not reproducible, unfortunately. `terra::rast()` does not have a `nlyr` argument (for character input). And `"elev.tif"` from `{terra}` is a single band raster, so I don't understand why you're trying to access a third layer here.

Comment: I ran it from my computer and it worked. I built off an example from Dr. Hijmans here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73625271/how-to-create-a-spatraster-from-dataframe

Comment: I'd clear the environment and start all over again. In the example referenced the input to `terra::rast()` is a SpatRaster object, behaving differently than a path to a file on disk. Also, his data frame object only has one column, without x/y dimensions. My gut tells me we are overcomplicating things here.  Does ClimateNA accept the following file? `system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") |> terra::rast() |> terra::writeRaster("elev.asc", NAflag = -9999)`

Comment: The terra elev.tif as elev.asc triggers the same error. I sent Dr. Wang (ClimateNA) this question as well.

Comment: Any chance to put hands on the raw example data that comes with ClimateNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raster file is required to be in a latitude-longitude projection (WGS84), prepared in ArcGIS or in R (QGIS format is not supported), and please make sure that the ASC file has proper line breaks (Windows format only). Here is the R code to convert a raster in TIF to ASC:
library(raster)

```
tif <- raster('C:/data/dem.tif')
NAvalue(tif) <- -9999
writeRaster(tif, 'C:/data/dem.asc',overwrite=TRUE)
```

If you use terra package, you need an extra step:

```
library(terra)
tif <- rast('C:/data/dem.tif')
writeRaster(r, 'dem0.asc',NAflag=-9999,overwrite=TRUE)

temp <- readLines('dem0.asc')
write.table(temp,'dem.asc', row.names=F,col.names=F,quote=F)
```

For detail, please check the Help at: https://climatena.ca/Help2#_use_raster

Comment: This worked for the terra example. But now if I run it with my DEM I seem to get further - it starts to say that it is processing. However, it immediately gives a 'Run-time error 63: Bad record number'. However, if I use the older raster package approach - it is slower but it worked.

Comment: I thought it was working and then the bad record number showed up.

Comment: Working now - updated version to most recent.

Comment: Extra - ClimateBC produces this error - CimateNA does not. The software author is looking to repair the problem, but ClimateNA is okay for my needs.